# How to use + between TIME_SPAN

Tags: ada, timespan

The question is about using the operator `+` between `TIME_SPAN` , for example:

```
T1 : ADA.REAL_TIME.MICROSECONDS(10);
T2 : ADA.REAL_TIME.MICROSECONDS(20);

T3 := T1 + T2
```

But the error that I get is:

> Binary operator "+" between Time_Span and Time_Span not directly visible, use clause or conversion might be needed"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure. Add `use type time_span` (i cannot test right now)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, `use type` is probably correct, although the type needs to be fully qualified; `use type Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span;`

Answer (score 3):

The message means that you need a "use clause" to make the `+` operator for `Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span` directly visible:

```ada
Example :
declare
   use type Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span;
begin
   T3 := T1 + T2;
end Example;
```